# Is it desirable to use Ansible for creating a docker image

Tags: docker, ansible

I know we can create docker images using ansible. I'm learning and doing POC work.

I'm trying to find what are the pros/cons of creating a docker image using Ansible.

Would like to hear if you have played and found any issues/solutions with creating docker images (NOT deploying docker images) using ansible?

Also, are there any good reasons not to create docker images using Ansible?

Comment: "Neccesary"? It isn't necessary, and never was. "Desirable" would be a different question, one not founded on a false premise.

Comment: What tool do you use or recommend for creating docker images?

Comment: Also, I'd tend to say that the appropriate course of action depends on the context of your shop: If your ops team deploys using ansible, that gives you a much stronger reason to use it (so the same playbooks used by ops are used by QA/test). If they don't, then you're in the realm of trying to choose one of N competing products -- a decision that doesn't really have a single right answer.

Comment: I mean, if I owned ops for my employer, we'd be a Chef shop, so we'd be using Chef across-the-board, including here. However, our ops team happens to be composed of people who are allergic to Ruby (not a language I'm fond of either, but I don't write off widely-tools for that reason) and haven't had the misfortune to be in a situation where having a devops framework with an inadequate featureset / overly limited DSL screwed them badly (a place I *have* been in the past), so they went a different route.

Comment: Point being: This is a very, _very_ opinion- and fact/individual-circumstance heavy decision. I'm not sure there's one right answer, and questions with One Right Answer are really what SO is best at.

Comment: That's fine, thanks for sharing your inputs Charles. I'm not sure about Chef/Puppet but definitely, our team is going to use Ansible. With puppet/Chef, things were getting more complex / big. Agree with you that Chef might be good for complex systems but we went with Ansible as it was more easier to understand, order/parallelism feature and was cheap in creating playbooks for small-medium setup.

Comment: Sometimes the system you're modeling is complex enough to need capabilities that something tiny and lightweight can't effectively represent. Sometimes it isn't, and something tiny and lightweight is just the thing. BTW, Puppet is what we were using back when I had my set of tool-inadequate-to-the-task experiences (for deploying a complex, heterogeneous cluster with numerous interlocking components to DCs with thousands of machines), which is what drove me to Chef.

Comment: ...of course, if the stack we were deploying and managing hadn't pushed as much complexity onto ops/management as it did, that experience might have been a completely different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a good choice.

- If an agentless system is good enough for your needs, keeping your Docker images lightweight (by not having any agent in them) is a reasonable thing to desire.
- If  your ops team uses Ansible, using the same playbooks in configuring your Docker images (used for dev/test) as for production is desirable.
- If your production environment uses Docker in the manner in which it's intended to be used, then you have reduced need for complex logic around maintenance and upkeep of existing systems, which makes Ansible a better option.

That said, I also have a laundry list of complaints about Ansible -- particularly, in places where its DSL is poorly designed in ways that make automating generation of playbooks error-prone, and places where functionality present in some of its competitors (albeit not particularly relevant to Docker image generation) was designed in only as an afterthought.

No tool is perfect; the decision in terms of what meets your needs and fails only in ways you find acceptable needs to be made in the context of your own use cases.